# Trying to update code to return HTML value in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am using Selenium to crawl some Facebook group information:

```
    with open("groups.txt") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    total = len(lines)
    count = 1
    for line in lines:

        group_id = line.strip().split(".com/")[1]
        if "groups" not in line:
            new_line = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/" + str(group_id) + "/about"
        else:
            new_line = line.strip() + '/about'
        sleep(2)
        driver.get(new_line)
        page_source = driver.page_source
        page_id = page_source.split('"groupID":"')[1].split('","')[0]
        page_followers = page_source.split('<!-- --> total members')[0][-15:]
        page_followers = str(page_followers.split('>')[1]).replace(',', '')
        page_name = page_source.split("</title>")[0].split("<title>")[1]

        df1.loc[len(df1)] = [line.strip(), 'https://www.facebook.com/' + str(page_id), page_followers, page_name]
        print(f"{count}/{total}", line.strip(), 'https://www.facebook.com/' + str(page_id), page_followers)
        count += 1
    df1.to_csv("groups.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)
```

Facebook has updated something recently so this code fails to return number of group members.

These are the relevant lines:

```
page_followers = page_source.split('<!-- --> total members')[0][-15:]
page_followers = str(page_followers.split('>')[1]).replace(',', '')
```

Taking view-source:https://www.facebook.com/groups/764385144252353/about as an example, I find two instances of "total members". Is it possible to get some advice on what I should change to be able to catch this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW

This code extract the exact number of members and convert it from string to integer

```
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/groups/410943193806268/about')
members = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'total members')]").text
members = int(''.join(i for i in members if i.isdigit()))
print(members)
```

output

```
15589
```

---

OLD

I suggest don't use `page_source` to extract this kind of data, instead use `find_element` in this way

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='members']").text.split()[0]
```

output

```
'186'
```

Explanation: `a[href*='members']` search for `a` elements (for example `<a class='test'>...</a>`) having a `href` attribute containing the string `members` (for example `<a href="something-members-test">...</a>`)

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much, but how did you find that href part in the HTML source code? Using this returns 15.5K instead of the full number 15,549 if we take https://www.facebook.com/groups/410943193806268/about as an example. How can I see what part I should reference to return the full number?

Comment: @hofebido I updated the answer with new code which extracts the full number. To find the HTML code of a web element, right click on it and select 'Inspect' or something similar. This will open the inspector tool with the HTML of the page. Then you can right click on the HTML code of the element and select 'Copy xpath' to get the string to insert inside `.find_element(By.XPATH, string)`

Comment: Ahhhh... Got it. You have been super helpful. Thank you enormously for guiding me through this! (It works like a charm!)